# Jensen Shannon divergence in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and was trying to find a function which calculates JS divergence in R.
I can see that R has KLdiv for calculating KL divergence, but is there anything available for JS divergence?

Answer (score 10):

I was looking for a simple implementation of the [JS divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence#Definition)  rather than an R library. Since I did not see one in any of the responses, I came up with the one below.

Assuming we have the following input distributions:

```
# p & q are distributions so their elements should sum up to 1
p <- c(0.00029421, 0.42837957, 0.1371827, 0.00029419, 0.00029419,
       0.40526004, 0.02741252, 0.00029422, 0.00029417, 0.00029418)

q <- c(0.00476199, 0.004762, 0.004762, 0.00476202, 0.95714168,
       0.00476213, 0.00476212, 0.00476202, 0.00476202, 0.00476202)
```

The Jensen-Shannon divergence would be:

```
n <- 0.5 * (p + q)
JS <- 0.5 * (sum(p * log(p / n)) + sum(q * log(q / n)))
> JS
[1] 0.6457538
```

For more than 2 distributions (which has already been discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/jensen-shannon-divergence-calculation-for-3-prob-distributions-is-this-ok)) we need a function to compute the [Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition):

```
H <- function(v) {
      v <- v[v > 0]
      return(sum(-v * log(v)))
}
```

Then the JS divergence would be:

```
JSD <- function(w, m) {
  return(H(m %*% w) - apply(m, 2, H) %*% w)
}

> JSD(w = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), m = cbind(p, q, n))
          [,1]
[1,] 0.4305025
```

Where `w` is a vector of weights which should sum up to 1 and `m` is a matrix with the input distributions as columns.

Comment: In the part for more than two distributions, we have two`m` `m = cbind(p, q, m)`.  It is confusing. Better to replace the `m` within brackets with something else, for consistency.

Comment: Thank you @Krantz, I replaced the vector `m` by `n` so that it is clear that the parameter to the JSD function refers to a matrix. Even though the syntax is allowed in R, you are correct it can be confusing.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone is still searching for an answer (I was), there is a function to calculate this in the R package phyloseq: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0061217

I also found this tutorial useful: http://enterotype.embl.de/enterotypes.html

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia Jensen-Shannon divergence is a transformation of the KL divergence. Applying the formula from the definition should give you the JS divergence then...

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence